# Limit hour DateTimePicker to 30 minute intervals

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, intervals

I have several DateTimePicker controls in C# and I need to limit the user to only choose from 30 minute intervals, e.g. 9:00 --> 9:30 --> 10:00 --> 10:30, and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: @GrantWinney you can do it like I show it.

Comment: Please check my implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (dt.Minute % 30 > 15)
        {
            initialValue = true;
            dateTimePicker1.Value = dt.AddMinutes(dt.Minute % 30);
        }
        else
        {
            initialValue = true;
            dateTimePicker1.Value = dt.AddMinutes(-(dt.Minute % 30));
        }

        _prevDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;

    }


    private DateTime _prevDate;
    private bool initialValue = false;

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(initialValue)
        {
            initialValue = false;
            return;
        }

        DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        TimeSpan diff = dt - _prevDate;

        if (diff.Ticks < 0) 
            dateTimePicker1.Value = _prevDate.AddMinutes(-30);
        else 
            dateTimePicker1.Value = _prevDate.AddMinutes(30);

        _prevDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    }
```

This should work.  You need global variable/Property to store _prevDate. You set the _prevDate in Form1() or on Form Load.

How we are adding/removing 30 minutes every time.

On value Change event you are taking the current dataPicker Value, after that you calculate the difference between currentValue and prevValue. If the value > 0 Add, and value<0 Remove.

If you don't know how to change the DatePicker to show minutes you need this to add in the designer.
You need this code:

```
        this.dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm";
        this.dateTimePicker2.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        this.dateTimePicker2.ShowUpDown = true;
```

EDIT:
I add the code which will start the DataPicker on 00 or 30 depending how close is to 30 or 00. You need another global variable of type bool which will put initialValue of the dateTimePicker. See the code.

Comment: @GrantWinney It can be make to starts from 00 or 30 this is not a problem. If you asking that

Comment: @GrantWinney here I add the code to start from 00 or 30.

Comment: At the first 'if' brace, there's an error. The correct line is:
`dateTimePicker1.Value = dt.AddMinutes(30 - dt.Minute % 30);`